# How to disable app preloading in Windows 10?

Tags: modern-ui, windows-10-preview

I'm running Windows 10 Insider Preview in my machine to give it a go and get used to it before general availability. One of the things that I find annoying is that it seems to preload modern (universal?) apps for them to open faster should you decide to use them probably.

For example, in the following screenshot of a task manager you can see 4 applications being *preloaded* (sort of opened, but suspended and not shown in the taskbar or any other place) which are the ones in grey. They were not even opened in that Windows session:

[image: Preloaded apps in Windows 10 Preview (the 4 in grey)]

I'd like to know if there's a way to disable this functionality.

Comment: you will probably waste your time on tweaking this version... just wait for final release, before tweaking it.

Comment: Your Pic shows they are services, much like the other optimisation services on the older windows, did you try setting the services to manuel, and disabling the ones you will not use?